# DB2 SQL Query via PHP not returning results

Tags: php, db2-400

Scratching my head as to why the below code won't work, needs some fresh eyes. Have tested SQL query in RazorSQL and it returns values but I can't get this to work in php. No connection or statement errors either. My guess is that this has something to do with 'i5_libl' but I haven't found any workarounds. Any ideas?

```
<?php

class employees
{
    private $employees = array();
    private $db_host = '*LOCAL';
    private $db_options = array(
        'i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON,
        'i5_libl' => 'CLTDTA CLTPAY'
    );
    
    public function getList() {
        $connection = db2_connect($this->db_host,$GLOBALS['db_user'],$GLOBALS['db_password'],$this->db_options);
        echo db2_conn_error();
        echo db2_conn_errormsg();
        $sql='SELECT F0101.ABAN8, F0101.ABALPH FROM F0101 INNER JOIN FP0102 ON F0101.ABAN8=FP0102.VEAN8 WHERE FP0102.VESTAT=\'\'';
        $stmt= db2_prepare($connection,$sql);
        echo db2_stmt_error();
        echo db2_stmt_errormsg();
        $result= db2_execute($stmt);
        while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            echo $row['ABAN8']; 
        }
        db2_close($connection);
        return true;            
    }
    
}
?>
```

!! Update:

I tried switching DB2_I5_NAMING_ON and DB2_I5_NAMING_OFF, with corrections to query, still nothing. Seems to me that this has more to do with the specific library (CLTDTA). When I run a vanilla SELECT query on just CLTPAY, I get a result fine. When I try the equivalent on CLTDTA, I don't get a result. The user, uses the system library list which contains references to all relevant libraries including CLTDTA.

Comment: I don't have anything to test against right now, but I believe by setting DB2_I5_NAMING_ON, you have to qualify your files using '/' instead of '.'. I would try disabling it to see if there is any change in behavior.

Comment: @Bob That was [changed back in 2012](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/System%20naming%20convention%20expanded%20to%20permit%20%28slash%29%20and%20%28dot%29%20qualifiers) with a Technology Refresh  (ie group PTF, like a service pack). As long as a system is kept even remotely up to date, that should not be the problem.

Comment: I tried switching DB2_I5_NAMING_ON and DB2_I5_NAMING_OFF, with corrections to query, still nothing. Seems to me that this has more to do with the specific library (CLTDTA). When I run a vanilla SELECT query on just CLTPAY, I get a result fine. When I try the equivalent on CLTDTA, I dont get a result. The user, uses the system library list which contains references to all relevant libraries including CLTDTA.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are being *echoed* for each step being performed **except** for the execute.  Add those same requests after the EXECUTE, just like is being done after the CONNECT and PREPARE steps.

If still nothing obvious, turn on the debug messaging feature [via the connection, by Start Service Job (STRSRVJOB) then Start Debug (STRDBG) on the job servicing the connection, or using the QAQQINI capabilities] and review the joblog for the job servicing the connection. Probably might just as well start a detailed database monitoring too; Start Database Monitor (STRDBMON) to verify the incoming statements. If still nothing is obvious from those, then also get a job trace, and then verify from the trace data [i.e. the effective *debug* trace DATA-records vs the execution FLOW-records], that the proper\expected files are being opened by the query request.